# How to set the ItemSource of an ListView Control with XPath

Tags: wpf, listview, xslt, wpf-controls, xslt-1.0

This question is a bit tricky because the whole code is auto generated via XSLT. This means I have to face a few limitations (no CodeBehind etc.)

I successfully generated a XAML File containing a ListView via XSLT. The XAML file contains also an XMLDataProvider. The DataSource and Provider are fine I just can't figure out how to set the XPath for the ListView ItemSource Property.

This is my data source:

```
<RelatedContacts>
        <Contact ShowsInterest="true">
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>
        </Contact >
        <Contact ShowsInterest="true">
            <Name>Max</Name>
            <Lastname>Mustermann</Lastname>
        </Contact >
        <Contact ShowsInterest="true">
            <Name>Claire</Name>
            <Lastname>Grube</Lastname>
        </Contact >
</RelatedContacts>
```

this is the generated ListView Code Snippet

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Contact/RelatedContacts/*}" Name="listview1" DockPanel.Dock="Left, Right, Top, Bottom" Height="125" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" FontStyle="Normal" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="True">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=../Contact/Name}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Lastname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=../Contact/Lastname}" />
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

this snippet displays the first item three times. (because there are three entries in the data source)
I tried a lot of other combinations but was not able to find a solution which could be generated with XSLT. This one works for example but i can't generate it with XSLT:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Contact/RelatedContacts//Contact}" Name="listview1" DockPanel.Dock="Left, Right, Top, Bottom" Height="125" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" FontStyle="Normal" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="True">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Name}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Lastname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Lastname}" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

As mentioned before, the ListView is generated. Here comes the "source" snippet which is transformed with XSLT

```
  <ListViewWrapper id="listview1" dock="Fill" text="" theme="" width="1078" height="125" backcolor="White" forecolor="Black" visible="True" mapNode="Contact\RelatedContacts" border-left="1" border-top="1" border-right="1" border-bottom="1" font-name="Tahoma" font-size="9" font-style="Regular">
    <TabIndex>0</TabIndex>
    <TabStop>True</TabStop>
    <Columns>
      <Column title="Name" mapNode="Contact\Name" width="0" />
      <Column title="Lastname" mapNode="Contact\Lastname" width="0" />
    </Columns>
  </ListViewWrapper>
```

While processing the ListViewWrapper and creating the ListView the XSLT Processor has no knowledge about the `mapNode` element of the columns because there deeper in the hierarchy. (I'm sure there is a way but I don't know how to do it.) Furthermore there is also the possibility the columns map to different elements like this.

```
<Columns>
  <Column title="Name" mapNode="Contact\Name" width="0" />
  <Column title="Lastname" mapNode="BusinessContact\Lastname" width="0" />
</Columns>
```

to wrap up, this is what I try to achieve:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Contact/RelatedContacts//*}
```

and then

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Name}" />
```

Display all child elements of RelatedContacts in the ListView without explicitly defining the whole path. I'm looking for something like a placeholder. Without this condition it would look like `XPath=/Contact/RelatedContacts//Contact`.

For those of interest here comes a part of the XSLT Stylesheet:

```
 <!-- Transformiere ListViewWrapper zu ListView -->
  <xsl:template match="ListViewWrapper">
    <xsl:element name="ListView">
      <xsl:attribute name="ItemsSource">
        <xsl:variable name="binding-path" select="./@mapNode"/>
        <xsl:variable name="bindpath" select="translate($binding-path, '\','/')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('{Binding XPath=/',$bindpath,'/*}')"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" mode="to-attr" />
      <xsl:element name="ListView.View">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ListView: Transformieren von Columns (Wrapper) zu GridView -->
  <xsl:template match="Columns">
    <xsl:element name="GridView">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ListView: Transformieren von Column zu GridViewColumn -->
  <xsl:template match="Column">
    <xsl:variable name="binding-path" select="./@mapNode"/>
    <xsl:element name="GridViewColumn">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:attribute name="Header">
        <xsl:value-of select="./@title" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="DisplayMemberBinding">
        <xsl:variable name="bindpath" select="translate($binding-path, '\','/')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('{Binding XPath=../',$bindpath,'}')"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:call-template name="listbox-width"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ListView: Setzen der Column width. Falls 0 dann nichts angeben (auto size) -->
  <xsl:template match="width" name="listbox-width">
    <xsl:if test="./@width != 0">
      <xsl:attribute name="Width">
        <xsl:value-of select="./@width" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Ausschluss des ListView Width Attribut -->
  <xsl:template match="ListViewWrapper/@width"
              mode="to-attr" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it the right way an it will work!

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Contact/RelatedContacts/*}" Name="listview1" DockPanel.Dock="Left, Right, Top, Bottom" Height="125" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" FontStyle="Normal" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="True">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Name}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Lastname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Lastname}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Age}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Street" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Street}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="City" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=City}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Postal code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=PostalCode}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Country" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Country}" />
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```